# Literal meaning of マタンゴ?

Tags: translation

The movie *Matango: Attack of the Mushroom People* is a very creepy 1963 movie in which fungus causes the transformation of humans into, indeed, Mushroom People. Google translate is no help and one search translated *"Matango"* into "Attack of the Mushroom People" which seems wrong to me. Google just translates it into English as *"matango"* which is not very helpful.

The movie is based on a turn of the 20th century short story which is called *The Voice in the Night* and I am wondering if the original title is somehow related to the word.

I find here: https://wikizilla.org/wiki/Matango#Name that the name is based on the name of a fungus which is called "mamadango" but this might be made up. It does make it seem less likely that the title is related to the original short story.

Comment: Never heard of it before, but looking at the plot summary, isn't "matango" just the name of the fictional mushroom that causes the infection or whatever?

Comment: Yes, just added that -- so maybe a nonsense word. I had limited Japanese in school but I thought the "go" part of the name might be related to the "voice" in the old short story's title but maybe not. I wonder how anyone found out about the name of the fungus -- I do not recall the movie well but perhaps this is stated by one of the characters.

Comment: [Jp wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B4) has a source: 名はキノコの一種であるママダンゴから採られた[33]  →^ DVD特典映像「製作ノート（劇場公開時パンフレットより）」. So probably the word is simply adapted from mamadango.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin of the word 'matango' is mentioned in the film's pamphlet, which refers to a real mushroom called 'mamadango'.　This is a reference to the Fukushima dialect 'mamadango', which refers to tuchiguri or tanukino-chabukuro.

Comment: thanks. but could the name also be a pun? in scifi stack exchange, i found the suggestion that the term might come from the spanish for killer fungus.

Comment: @releseabe: I think any Spanish derivation is a stretch. 1) There is no Spanish word _matango_, as we see by the lack of any entry in the _Diccionario de la lengua española_ provided by the Real Academia Española [here](https://dle.rae.es/matango?m=form). Closest we get is _matungo_, which means instead _"said of a horse: that it lacks good physical qualities"_. 2) This _might_ be a blend of [_matando_](https://dle.rae.es/matar) ("killing") + [_hongo_](https://dle.rae.es/hongo) ("fungus"), but a) this is a weird coinage, and b) Japanese movie-makers are unlikely to be this fluent in Spanish.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi: agree, a stretch but japanese tend to speak mto language and the first western language that was learned in japan centuries ago was spanish, i think.

Comment: @releseabe, in the modern Japanese school system, foreign language education of anything other than English is not common. I speak from first-hand experience teaching in Japanese schools in a couple different prefectures. Consider also that there is a native fungus with a name similar to _matango_. Just in terms of [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), Spanish _matando_ + _hongo_ → _matango_ seems much more of an unlikely stretch than native Japanese _mamadango_ → _matango_.

Comment: Consider too native Japanese _mata_ ("again; also; in addition, moreover") in reference to "something additional, something else", fitting in this movie with the idea of people becoming something else as the fungus takes over.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi: I agree, a stretch that it came from Spanish. I think your "again" idea is also a stretch. Although an extreme longshot, I see that many of the actors, despite the movie being 60 years old, are still with us and perhaps one of them actually knows the derivation. I think movie trivia is very interesting but accept that many things will remain a mystery and this is probably an example of at least something we will never be completely sure about.